# (Problems Using Charts) WPF .net 4.5

Tags: wpf, charts, .net-4.5

I have been trying to set up a function to plot some series of data, and the Chart control always gives some errors, and it is really annoying, because there are no proper tutorials for this control.

So far I have this code:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

public DataTable results;

public void plot ( Chart chr ) {    
    int cols = results.Columns.Count;
    int rows = results.Rows.Count;
    for ( int j = 1 ; j < cols ; j++ ) {
        //Add serie
        string name = results.Columns[j].ColumnName;

        //add data for the serie
        List<PlotValue> values = new List<PlotValue>( );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ ) {
            DateTime? x = results.Rows[i][0] as DateTime?; //time
            double y = double.Parse( results.Rows[i][j].ToString( ) ); //Value
            values.Add( new PlotValue( x , y ) );
        }

        LineSeries serie = new LineSeries();
        serie.LegendItems.Add( name );
        serie.ItemsSource = values;
        chr.Series.Add( serie );
    }
}
```

"results", is a DataTable that is modified by another asynchronous process, so I just want to read it when this other process finish.

I've also defined this class:

```
public class PlotValue {
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public PlotValue ( DateTime? date , double val ) {
        Date = date;
        Value = val;
    }
}
```

So far the error is that it tells me that there are no axes (which makes sense) and I have no clue on how to add them.

Please I want to use NO XAML at design time, just C# code at run time, because the number of series might change.

Alternatively I would move to any other control more straight forward that anyone has experience with.

I'm on .net 4.5, and the chart control belongs to [System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `Please I want to use NO XAML at design time, just C# code at run time, because the number of series might change.` - XAML doesn't force you to static stuff. Im not familiar with these charts but I'm sure there is an MVVM way to do what you need, instead of resorting to that horrible `for` loop. WPF is not winforms. Learn MVVM.

Comment: Try to call the `plot` method after the chart is loaded (by using the `Chart.Loaded` event)